# writing % in NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, nsstring, escaping

I am writing a sqlite like query . i need a query like this :

select name like %name%

code for doing this :

```
str1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" ri.name like ' \% %@ \%'", [array objectAtIndex:i]];
```

but this not give me desired result.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To use `%` in a format string you should use `%%` instead of `\%`.

Answer (score 3):

Use this format `%%` instead of `/%`.And try to use like this

```
  str1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@" ri.name like  %% %@ %%",[array objectAtIndex:i]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Talking about SQL, one thing that the others aren't saying is that you are putting spaces before and after the `%`characters,

What the other answers will print is something like this:

```
@" ri.name like  % example %"
```

And that will look for subStrings in your table with those spaces after and before.

Maybe what you are looking for is:

```
str1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" ri.name like ' %%%@%%'", [array objectAtIndex:i]];
```

Which will print:

```
@" ri.name like  %example%"
```